# Callout action from Annotations in Map view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an array of latitudes and longitudes along with other stuffs and I want to create annotations in Map view. I’m using MapKit.

When ever the user clicks the annotation callout I’m going to present another controller. I’m not able to find the index of the array element that was used to create that particular annotation.

Below is my code.

I have a Int variable

```
var annotationIndex = 0
```

This is where I add annotations

```
func addAnnotation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, title: String, subTitle: String?) {
    if (latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90) && (longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180) {
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = title
        annotation.subtitle = subTitle
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

This is an MKMapViewDelegate method to customize annotation

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
{
    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation)
    {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"
    var aView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    aView.canShowCallout = true

    let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnDisclosureAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = annotationIndex
    annotationIndex++

    aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

    return aView
}
```

This is the rightCalloutAccessoryView Button Action

```
func btnDisclosureAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println(sender.tag)
}
```

Right now I'm just printing the callout diusclosure button tag which I try setting it using an annotationIndex variable.

Since the annotationView is reused I cannot get the exact index value.Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Below is my code. But Where ?

Comment: I can help you with Objective-C, if you can convert it into swift.

Comment: @ViralSavaj  Sure, any kind of help is appreciable. I will convert it to swift.

Comment: @Matt, have a look at my answer, I have converted my Obj-C code to Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass MKPointAnnotation to have index value.

```
class
Annotation  :   MKPointAnnotation {
    var index = 0
}
```

And set index when annotation is created.

```
let annotation = Annotation()

    :

annotation.subtitle = subTitle
annotation.index = annotationIndex++
```

Pass annotation's index to btn

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnDisclosureAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
btn.tag = ( annotation as! Annotation ).index
```

EDIT:
So your viewForAnnotation will be

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
{
    if !(annotation is Annotation)
    {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"
    var aView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    aView.canShowCallout = true

    let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnDisclosureAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = ( annotation as! Annotation ).index

    aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

    return aView
}
```

Comment: Using a custom subclass instead of MKPointAnnotation _is_ going in the right direction.  However, the button tag (and addTarget) are unnecessary since map view will call `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method when an accessory view is tapped (the custom button handler method is not needed).  In that delegate method, the annotation is retrieved using `view.annotation`.  If you cast it to the custom annotation class, you can then directly retrieve the custom index property from the annotation.

Comment: Thanks Satachito. I tried the exact same thing but nothing happened. Do you know any link that shows how to Subclass MKPointAnnotation? I thing thats where my lies.

Comment: How to subclass MKPointAnnotation is described in very beginning of my answer. Did you replace 'let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()' with 'let annotation = Annotation()' ?

Answer (score 0):

Specify `indexselected` as class variable and initilise it with -1 in `viewDidLoad` method ,like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    indexselected = -1
}
```

You can get your annotation index while user tap on annotation, and `didSelectAnnotationView` method get called automatically.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    var selectedAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as! MKPointAnnotation
    for var i = 0; i<yourlist.count ; i++ {
        let strtitle : String = yourlist.objectAtIndex(i).title as! String
        if selectedAnnotation.title == strtitle  {
            indexselected=i
            break
        }
    }
}
```

We can get annotation index by comparing title on annotation and title from your array, and save the index from array. On selection of button method you can use that index.

```
func btnDisclosureAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println(indexselected)
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you @Viral, but I think Satachito answer solved my problem because I might get same titles which will definitely be a problem. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Welcome @Matt, Satachito's answer is also a nice way to achieve what you want.